# Removing data after query

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I need help writing this LINQ query, here is what I want to do - I have two tables

```
Message
===
Name
MessageTypeID  -> Foreign Key
Date

MessageType
===
ID **(the foreign key)
Name
```

My Get API method returns a JSON object with the following structure:

```
- List<MessageType>
- Name
- List<Message>
```

Question: I would like the List of messages within the messagetype object to be filtered to only include messages with a date less than today.

My first solution was to do the following - but that just returns the first messagetype object many times over.

```
var mt = from m in db.MessageType
         join l in db.Message on m.MessageTypeID equals l.MessageTypeID
         where m.SenderID == id && l.Date < DateTime.Now
         select m;
return mt.AsEnumerable();
```

I then tried to remove the join and remove data after the query, but that caused an exception.

```
var myList = mt.ToList();
foreach (var mtype in myList)
{
    foreach (var mess in mtype.LibMessages)
    {
        if (mess.VisibleEndDate < DateTime.Now)
        {
            // remove expired message. 
            mtype.LibMessages.Remove(mess);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "... caused an exception". What exception?

Comment: I am using entity framework 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the collection your are iterating on in ForEach
Please modify the inner loop as follows:

```
var myList = mt.ToList();
foreach (var mtype in myList)
{
    foreach (var mess in mtype.LibMessages.ToList())
    {
        if (mess.VisibleEndDate < DateTime.Now)
        {
            // remove expired message. 
            mtype.LibMessages.Remove(mess);
        }
    }
}
```